# Reading mapfile

Tags: python, map-files

What's wrong with this code? Showing module not found error.

**CODE:**

```
data_dir = 'D://ob//Imag'
mapfile = os.path.join(data_dir,'map.txt')

# Read the mapfile:
with open(mapfile,'r') as fp:
    
    mp = (
        st.strip().split('  ')\
        for st in fp.readlines()
    )
    
    fixpath = lambda x: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(data_dir,x))
    mp = [
        (fixpath(x[0]), fixpath(x[1]))\
        for x in mp
    ]

label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict('D://ob//Imag//abc.pbtxt')
```

**ERROR:**

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-96f2621dd3fd> in <module>()
      3 
      4 # Read the mapfile:
----> 5 with open(mapfile,'r') as fp:
      6 
      7     mp = (

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D://ob//Imag/map.txt'
```

Comment: Don't use double forward slashes here, either single forward slashes or (Windows only) double backslashes.

Comment: Then also its showing error

Comment: Do you have `map.txt` file in your 'D://ob//Imag/` directory?

Comment: The exactly same error? If not, show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: @Ahx Yes map.txt is present there

Comment: I think the problem is `D://ob//Imag/map.txt` the missing `/` before `map.txt`. Try with `D://ob//Imag//map.txt`

Comment: Is the entire code syntax ok?